# Preventing EntityReference Checks from occuring when Creating/Updating an Entity in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

When executing a CreateRequest using the MS CRM OrganizationService, it seems that any attribute of type 'EntityReference' is checked by the internal CRM pipeline using a SQL query against the respective base table looking for the key specified in the EntityReference object. It's basically a foreign key check substitute since CRM doesn't define actual foreign keys when you relate entities.

I'm trying to import some data into the system where I know the specified EntityReference's already exist since I just retrieved them (race conditions aside). Is there any way to bypass that internal check from happening when using the web services? I'd like to avoid having to do any direct SQL updates since it invalidates the auditbase and modifiedby information.

For example, inserting 100,000 entity instances which each have 5 entity reference attributes on them turns into 500,000 selects being issued, often for the same value. Please tell me there is a supported way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The only supported way to create records inside Dynamics CRM is to use the API.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not looking to not use the api, but rather influence the content of the requests to avoid tons of individual selects to determine if a value exists in another table or not.

Comment: I understood your question, but the answer is still no (answers on stackoverflow require a minimum length), you have only the API to create records and if the behavior is the one you described than there are no alternatives